# how can i make a multiple video preview before uploading the multiple selected videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have been trying to configure the code below in order to achieve a multiple video preview but its not working and it works well with only a single video.
can someone out their help me please.Thanks

Here is my scripting code for javascript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`enter code here`

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {

 var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        // Only process video files.
        if (!f.type.match('video.*')) {
            continue;
        }


  var $source = $('#video_here');

      var source = document.getElementById("video_here");
      var source = document.createElement('video');//added now


   $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

  $source.parent()[0].load();


  }


});
</script>

      This is my HTML for video 



                                            <video  controls>

                                               <label for="select video">Select video/Multiple videos</label>

                                               <source  src="video/*"  id="video_here">
                                                    Your browser does not support HTML video.

                                                  </video>

                Here is my input type which contains the the file type for selecting files and here i include an attribute multiple for selecting multiple files
```

Comment: There are several issues with code at Question. Why is `source` variable declared twice? Is requirement for each uploaded file to be set at a different `<video>` element?

Comment: `<source  src="video/*"` I don't think that will work, how is the browser supposed to know what to request? you need to give actual file name here

Comment: ok. thanks a lot for your time.but please can you help me to fix it for me because as i have told you,i have tried many way and i have failed and am somehow new to javascript.help me please

Comment: @n.ssendawula What is expected result? Multiple `<video>` elements appended to `document`, one for each uploaded file?

Comment: What i want is that each selected video ihas a preview before uploading all the multiple selected videos

Comment: if any one can help me please

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need you to update your question and add some more information. Tell us what you tried, what the results were. what you have researched, any error messages? screenshots? etc? also show us (with some sample code or a photoshop screenshot) what you'd like it to look like when it's done. "it's not working" just doesn't help us to help you figure out what's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `i` variable within `for` loop, use a single declaration for `source`, use `.appendChild()` to append the created `<video>` element to the `document.body` or other parent element

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
  .onchange = function(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var f = files[i];
      // Only process video files.
      if (!f.type.match('video.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var source = document.createElement('video'); //added now

      source.width = 280;

      source.height = 240;

      source.controls = true;

      source.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);

      document.body.appendChild(source); // append `<video>` element

    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" accepts="video/*" multiple>
```

Comment: Thank dear may God bless you.am going to try it out thanks

Comment: i have tried to use the same codes in my work but it seems it is not displaying the videos.is there anything else i have to add?.thanks

Comment: can someone help me please?

Comment: someone should help me please

Comment: You should have to add anything else. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate the issue that you are having?

Comment: ok.the name of the selected video is displayed beside the button.but no video preview appears.

Comment: Sir.i appreciate your work.i have tried to configure the code but it has totally failed to work in my script.therefore i was wondering if you can find me another code that can do it .like an alternative solution.thanks

Comment: @n.ssendawula Not certain how code at Answer "totally failed"? Does code at stacksnippets render expected result?

Comment: no it doesn't output the video.it just output the name beside the button.

Comment: Ok. Sir.I have now had a change that i can now view the videos in the body of my browser but can you help mi on how i can make it to a specific div because i wanted them to appear in a specific place.thank you.

Comment: `$("#specificDiv").append(source)`

Comment: indeed sir,i want to thank you for your time you have given me up to now.i have managed to make it work.thanks a lot

Comment: Sir how can insert an icon to cancel a video which has been uploaded by mistake.

Comment: @n.ssendawula What do you mean by "cancel"?