# Append a video upload preview to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a preview of the video files and futurely other file types as well. Ive found an answer that got me started here:
[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637100/how-can-i-make-a-multiple-video-preview-before-uploading-the-multiple-selected-v)

Im successfully previewing it unto the body but im displayed always a notice message in the html document regardless to whether  works or not:

> [object HTMLUnknownElement][object HTMLElement][object HTMLUnknownElement]

Moving forward ive added to the script from previewing it in the body to a div with li elements.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = function(event) {
var files = event.target.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var f = files[i];

    if (f.type.match('video.*')) { // Only process video files.
        var source = document.createElement('video'); //added now
        source.width = 280;
        source.height = 240;
        source.controls = true;
        source.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);
        //document.body.appendChild(source); // append `<video>` element to body "original part from answer"

        var div = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');
        var previewF = '<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="'+f.name+'" type="'+f.type+'"></video>';
        var div2='<li id="slide'+i+'">'+source+'</li>';

        //div.appendChild(div2); //display method 1
        div.innerHTML += div2; //display method 2

        var divb = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails');
        var div3='<li><a href="#slide'+i+'">'+source+'</a></li>';
        //divb.appendChild(div3); // append `<video>` element
        divb.innerHTML += div3;

    }
}
}
```

If i use the commented method 2 in in script "div.innerHTML += div2;", i get the same message html message in the body quoted in the top but doesnt display the desired contend.
When i use the method 1 instead "div.appendChild(div2);" it now say in the debug console:

> TypeError: div.appendChild is not a function

And doesnt show anything as well. Note, "var previewF" is just an alternative to "source" and the following "div3" and so on is repetition for same problem to display the thumbnails "just a placeholder" im not obviously use an actual video for thumbnail while i have it in a bigger element xD.

I hope somebody can help me out, ive been searching and trying different ways but i end up in the same trouble for some reason.

Comment: Have a look at this solution for the `TypeError`: [AppendChild() is not a function javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673995/11700321)

Comment: Thank you for your help, ive tried their answers but im still with the one of the same two errors here is an example i use instead from them:                                                                    var div4 = document.createElement('li');
div4.setAttribute("id", "slide"+i);
var node = document.createTextNode(source);
div4.appendChild(node);
//div.appendChild(div4);
div.innerHTML += div4;  if i use again appendChild  says its not a function the inner gives html message and no content.

Comment: have you tried .append()

Comment: Hi, ive just tried and still says "TypeError: div.append is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seams that ive found a partial answer to my problem.

The culprit is the "getElementsByClassName()" method to select the wrapper div. The problem with this is that it returns an HTMLCollection, an array-like object, not the element object that's needed by the appendChild() method. So now i know that i shouldnt use a class for append() but id instead.

By replacing it im facing another bit of a problem *sigh.. if i append the source object directly to the now div/ul by id wrapper it works but if use the variable that creates a li element with the video now says the following as plain text:

> < li id="slide0">[object HTMLVideoElement]< /li>

*Ignore the space in the quote of li because of this text editor in stack

So after some more search ive found the solution! I replaced the way i append the text again and voila.

Here is the updated script now working as intended.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = function(event) {
var files = event.target.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var f = files[i];

    if (f.type.match('video.*')) { // Only process video files.
        // section for the large display
        var previewF = '<video width="100%" height="240" controls> <source src="'+URL.createObjectURL(f)+'" type="'+f.type+'"></video>';
        var div1='<li id="slide'+i+'">'+previewF+'</li>';
        $("#slides").append(div1); //The append method replacement

        // section for the thumbnails, again as a placeholder ;)
        var previewF2 = '<video width="100%" height="240" controls> <source src="'+URL.createObjectURL(f)+'" type="'+f.type+'"></video>';
        var div2='<li><a href="#slide'+i+'">'+source+'</a></li>';
        $("#thumbnails").append(div2);
    }}}
```

*Ive edited this answer with the now working code.